# Alsa mixer mutes headphones every time I plug them

Tags: sound, 13.04, alsa, headphones

Ever since I updated my laptop from 12.10 to 13.04 I've been experiencing a strange behaviour with my Ubuntu installation. Every time I plug in my headphones the volume becomes mute. I can only unmute them through AlsaMixer.

[image: AlsaMixer]

It is annoying to do this every time I want to listen my music, could somebody point me to a fix or workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Laptop: HP Pavilion dv6 6185la